# Puntero this en función con objeto por referencia

Tags: c++

Buenas a todos,

estudiando un trozo de código, he comprobado estas líneas:

```
Persona& operator=(const Persona& otra)
{
  if (this!=otra)
  {
   delete [] nombre_;
  edad_ = otra.edad_;
  ...
  }
}
```

NOTA: No expongo el código completo para simplificar.

Lo que me gustaría conocer, si la función sobrecargada del operador `=` recibe un objeto `otra` por referencia, la siguiente línea:

```
this != otra
```

Como se diría a efectos formales, ¿qué está consiguiendo?

Porque hasta donde he entendido this es la dirección de memoria del objeto creado, es decir, la dirección de memoria del objeto otra.
¿Compara si el objeto `this` es distinto de `otra`?
¿Cuál es el objeto `this` y cuál es `otra`? ¿Es el mismo objeto lo que compara?

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código parece el habitual caso de implementación de operador de asignación con verificación de auto-asignación.

La verificación de auto-asignación se hace para evitar que asignar un objeto sobre si mismo tenga algún efecto:

```
struct S {};

S s;
s = s; // auto asignacion
```

En el caso de tu clase `Persona` el problema de la auto-asignación es evidente, dado que borras el contenido de la formación<sup>1</sup> `nombre_`, sería problemático si el objeto se estuviese guardando sobre si mismo pues borrarías la formación<sup>1</sup> y después asignarías el mismo puntero borrado sobre si mismo.

Una vez explicada la (posible) motivación tras tu código, hay que decir que no se pueden comparar referencias y punteros<sup>2</sup> (ni viceversa). Tu código no compila. Seguramente le falta un `&`:

```
if (this!=&otra)
//        ~ <--- direccion de
```

El código anterior compara dos punteros y no debería fallar salvo que `Persona` implemente el operador unario `&`, para solventar ese caso se puede usar [`std::addressof`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

O te falta un `*`:

```
if (*this!=otra)
//  ~ <--- des-referenciar
```

El código anterior compara dos instancias del objeto, pero para que sea posible el objeto debe implementar el operador de inequidad `!=`.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como arreglo, o array en inglés.

<sup>2</sup>Excepto, si [como dice eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131368/2742), hay algún operador sobrecargado.

Comment: Muy claro, muchísimas gracias @Paula_plus_plus desde luego estaba estudiando eso exactamente, implementando el operator operator= jejeje Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (this!=otra)
```

Efectivamente, `this` es un puntero, mientras que `otra` es una referencia... Esa línea no debería ser compilable salvo que exista una sobrecarga del operador `!=` que reciba un puntero y una referencia:

```
class Persona;
bool operator!=( Persona const* a, Persona const& b)
{
  return a != &b;
}
```

Como no creo que esto sea así, entiendo que la intención real era que la línea luciese más bien así:

```
if( this != &otra )
```

Esta línea se utiliza como método rudimentario para evitar copiar un objeto sobre sí mismo lo cual, dado que existe un `delete[]` implicaría la pérdida irremediable de información.

Comment: Es cierto, me equivoqué, era la dirección de memoria del objeto otra (&otra) con el puntero this, que tiene la dirección de memoria, entonces compararía direcciones como bien decís. Gracias! @eferion